# Symfony - VichUploaderBundle not working after composer update

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I am using `VichUploaderBundle` and I am running into the error

> The class "AppBundle\Entity\Resume" is not uploadable. If you use
>   annotations to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot
>   to add `@Vich\Uploadable` on top of your entity. If you don't use
>   annotations, check that the configuration files are in the right
>   place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue.

I am not using `Annotations` and all my mappings are done via `YAML` so from the [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-2-link-the-upload-mapping-to-an-entity) it says to use YAML configuration [this](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/mapping/yaml.md) way which I have followed bit still I do not understand why i get this error

Inside my `config.yml` I have

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        image_mapping:
            uri_prefix:         '%amazon_s3_asset_url%'
            upload_destination: aws_s3
            inject_on_load:     true
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

Inside my `AppBundle/Resources/config/vich_uploader/Resume.yml` I have

```
AppBundle\Entity\Resume:
    profileImage:
        mapping:           image_mapping # required
        filename_property: profileImage     # required
        size:              imageSize
        mime_type:         imageMimeType
        original_name:     imageOriginalName
```

**Important: A while ago this setup was working perfectly fine till I ran `composer update` and after that I see the error I mentioned above.**

The composer update command threw the following output.

```
Package operations: 0 installs, 19 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating twig/twig (v2.3.2 => v2.4.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-util (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.3.0 => v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating nelmio/api-doc-bundle (2.13.1 => 2.13.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (2.5.4 => v2.6.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating twig/extensions (v1.5.0 => v1.5.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating stripe/stripe-php (v4.9.1 => v4.13.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating aws/aws-sdk-php (3.28.2 => 3.29.8): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/phpunit-bridge (v3.2.8 => v3.3.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating behat/transliterator (v1.1.0 => v1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.4.28 => v2.4.29): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating monolog/monolog (1.22.1 => 1.23.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating vich/uploader-bundle (1.5.3 => 1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating knplabs/gaufrette dev-master (5df82e4 => d3ea4d5):  Checking out d3ea4d5a76
  - Updating knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle dev-master (cdfae2c => 855fc75):  Checking out 855fc75cbd
```

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Did you try declaring the path of the configuration file explicitly ? in your config.yml and did you clear your cache ? Also check this issue on github:
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/721 might be related ?

Comment: @Jeroen I ended up reverting to previous version of the bundle and everything started working fine.

Comment: I must say I am getting this too and rolling it back was all I could do.